# Postgres select and update in same query

Tags: join, sql-update, postgresql-9.4

I want to do a select and update in a single query in PostgreSQL 9.4. I used below command for that

```
UPDATE (SELECT t2.pid, t1.pid as newid
 FROM table1 AS t1
 INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 
 ON t1.uid = t2.uid
 ) AS t
SET t.newid = t.pid';
```

When executing the above, I'm getting below error.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 2:                 (SELECT t2.pid, t1.pid as n...
                        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 25
```

I executed

```
SELECT t2.pid, t1.pid as newid
 FROM table1 AS t1
 INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 
 ON t1.uid = t2.uid
```

part separately and I worked fine. Do I miss something in the update query?

Answer (score 1):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) the target in an UPDATE can not be a SELECT statement.

But you can use a FROM clause to join another table to the actual target table:

```
UPDATE t1
   set pid = t2.pid
FROM table2 as t2
WHERE t2.uid = t1.uid;
```